# How to make div columns float in tighter?

Tags: css, html, css-float

**[My CodePen](http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wzumq)**: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wzumq

Hi, so today I have a 6 column layout (3 columns per row). The 3rd column is really long, almost like a side bar.

Per the design columns 4 and 5 need to be up close to the bottom of columns 1 and 2 (with lets say 10px padding).

Problem is, since I have everything currently floated left, the long column 3 is creating too much space between the bottom of columns 1 & 2 and the top of columns 4 & 5.

I want to keep the position of the divs as is because when on smaller browser windows I'll have some adaptive code to restyle them.

Is there an easy way to do this? Or would I have to put column 4 inside another column underneath 1, and the same for column 5 and 2? Then when the screen sizes change use jQuery to re-position the divs?

**Current Problem:**
[image]

---

**What I'm trying to go for:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way i see to do this is by wrapping col1-col4, col2-col5, col3-col6 and make the wrappers floating left.
then if you want to make it responsive according to the resolution of the screen you can use @media queries and respond.js.

here is a brief explanation of what you should do:

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper1">
<div class="col1">content here</div>
<div class="col4">content here</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
<div class="col2">content here</div>
<div class="col5">content here</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper3">
<div class="col3">content here</div>
<div class="col6">content here</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper1, .wrapper2, .wrapper3{float:left;}
```

here you can find [your codepen updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eptwl)
here you can learn more about [respond.js and css media queries](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond)

Comment: Thanks! That does work, so does seem that I'll need to use jQuery to re-position the divs on smaller browser window sizes.

Comment: yes as i said respond.js can make the css media queries crossbrowser.
media queries are used to add different styles on different screen resolution.

Comment: Take a look at my solution that uses css3 and media queries for any window resize :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options, and [this article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/masonry/) explains them very well.

1. Javascript/jQuery plugin ([like jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)) that performs this function on all browsers
2. CSS-only option of using CSS columns (explained in the article), knowing full well that this isn't supported on IE9- and throwing caution into the wind!

That's pretty much it in terms of attaining a masonry layout like you want.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You'll see, it's pretty simple :) Close the tab on the left and you'll see the code :)